# cakephp dropdown box data not saving to database

Tags: database, cakephp

hi all the data from my dropdown box isn't saving correctly to the database, its saving to the foreign key `template_id` as `null`

here is the function

```
  function add(){


$this->Session->setFlash("Please create your required fields.");
$templates = $this->Template->find('all', array('fields' => array('Template.id' )));
$this->set('templates', $templates);

    if($this->request->is('post'))
    {

    $this->Field->create(); 

    if ($this->Field->save($this->request->data)) 
    {   
        if($this->request->data['submit'] == "type_1") 
            { 
                $this->Session->setFlash('The field has been saved');  
                $this->redirect( array('controller' => 'fields','action' => 'add'));
            } 
            if($this->request->data['submit'] == "type_2") 
            { 
                $this->Session->setFlash('The template has been saved'); 
                $this->redirect( array('controller' => 'templates','action' => 'index'));
            } 


    }
    else
    {
        $this->Session->setFlash('The field could not be saved. Please, try again.'); 
    } 
 } 
  }
```

here is the view

```
<?php

echo $this->Form->create('Field', array('action'=>'add'));

echo $this->Form->create('Field', array('action'=>'add'));
echo $this->Form->input('name', array('label'=>'Name: '));
echo $this->Form->input('description', array('label'=>'Description: '));
echo $this->Form->input('template_id',array('label'=>'Template ID: ', 'options' => $templates));
echo $this->Form->button('Continue adding fields', array('name' => 'submit', 'value' => 'type_1'));
echo $this->Form->button('Finish adding fields', array('name' => 'submit', 'value' => 'type_2'));
echo $this->Form->end();

 ?>
```

Comment: Explain what `pr($this->request->data)` shows?

Comment: Array
(
    [submit] => type_2
    [Field] => Array
        (
            [name] => test1
            [description] => hi
            [template_id] => 100000
        )

)

Comment: If the above array you received then it should be saved.

Comment: What type of field is template_id? It could only become null if `100000` is an input that your database cannot store into the specified field type (e.g. if it's a TINYINT(2) field or something, that will never work). Other than that the data seems valid and CakePHP should not be the cause of the problem.

Comment: What happens if you set `$this->request->data['Field']['template_id']` to something valid immediately before saving? If this still fails, then you likely have a database problem, not a Cake problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry guys it was a long day, it is saving the correcting  information.

Comment: but how ? you didn't explain for the viewers that come later and search for an answer. thanks